# Is there a way to download all of my Ubuntu One files?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, downloads

So, I have Ubuntu One on my mac, and is synced with the Ubuntu One website. I have folders within folders, within folders, and so on. If I needed to (If, I got a new computer, for example), would it be possible to download everything from the website in a big compressed file (zip, tar.gz, 7z, etc.)? If not, how would I go about downloading all of the files from the website to my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply install the Ubuntu One client on the new computer, log in with it to your account, and subscribe to all the folders you have on the server, it will download everything to the new machine.

There is no way to download all your data directly from the web site currently, via a zip or similar file.

Also note that Ubuntu One is more than only a file sync service, as there is also `u1db` for synchronization of structured data, which apps can use, and which may not be directly accessible via the web site at all, depending on what data is stored there. Accessing any data from apps which use `u1db` will also require installing them and associating them to your Ubuntu One account, so that they can sync up on the new machine.